# Can Stream's SKIP method making an infinite stream finite?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, ocpjp

"The `limit()` and `skip()` methods make a `Stream` smaller. They could make a finite stream smaller, or they *could make a finite stream out of an infinite stream*. The method signatures are shown here:

```
Stream<T> limit(int maxSize)
Stream<T> skip(int n)
```

The following code c...."

The above is an excerpt from OCP java 8 book. When it said "*could make a finite stream out of an infinite stream*", did they mean it in both the methods together or alone? I can imagine how `limit()` would make an infinite stream smaller, but how `skip()` alone would accomplish that? Is there a way or the wording in the documentation needs to be clearer?

Comment: I guess they have some miswording here. I will say that they can `together` create a finite stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"could make a finite stream out of an infinite stream"* is surely applicable to `limit()` only, not to to `skip()`.

`skip` is like taking a cup of water from the ocean and wondering "how much water is left in the ocean?", whereas `limit` is like taking the same cup of water from it and wondering "how much water did I take from the ocean?"

If the stream is infinite, then skipping a number of elements will still leave you with an infinite stream...

```
Stream.iterate(0L, i -> i + 1).skip(100).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will theoretically run forever. So chances are it's just a minor inaccuracy that escaped the reviewer of the book.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the Java doc carefully you will see that for `limit(long maxSize)` it is mentioned that it is a **short circuiting** operation. That means it may not operate on all elements of the source stream as soon as the given criteria is satisfied it will exit. So this works in changing a infinite Stream to a finite one.

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, truncated
>   to be no longer than maxSize in length.
>
> This is a **short-circuiting** stateful intermediate operation.

The `skip(long n)` method on the other hand makes no such claims, so basically after skipping n elements the Stream could still be infinite:

> Returns a stream consisting of the remaining elements of this stream
>   after discarding the first n elements of the stream. If this stream
>   contains fewer than n elements then an empty stream will be returned.
>
> This is a stateful intermediate operation.

So the book you are reading has the wording incorrect about the `skip` method.